# JSF 2.3 Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiValidator error

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.3

I've just converted from JSF2.2 to JSF2.3 using WIldfly18/Mojarra 2.3.9.SP04, and I'm getting the following error when invoking a JSF page using the custom validator with custom attrributes:
`SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.meta] (default task-26) /com.example.webpages/createIE815.xhtml @426,105 validatorMessage="my error message" Unhandled by MetaTagHandler for type com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiValidator`
The error doesn't occur in JSF2.2. It occurs in JSF2.3 even if the TagLib header still refers to version 2.2.

The taglib is specified as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_3.xsd" 
    version="2.3">
    
    <namespace>http://example.com/emcstags</namespace>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>validateReqdAndOpt</tag-name>
        <validator>
            <validator-id>com.example.validators.ValidateReqdAndOpt</validator-id>
        </validator>
        <attribute>
            <name>applyValidator</name>
            <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>validatorMessage</name>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag> 

</facelet-taglib>
```

I get the error for both attributes, repeated each time the custom validator is referenced.

The JSF page is still displayed and functions, but indeed the attributes are not supplied to the validator, so it does not function as intended.

How can I fix the error?

Here is the (somewhat lengthy) custom validator (with thanks to @BalusC for the concept):

```
package com.example.validators;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator(value = "com.example.validators.ValidateReqdAndOpt", managed = true)
public class ValidateReqdAndOpt implements Validator, Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ValidateReqdAndOpt.class.getName());
    private static final String DEFAULT_VALIDATOR_MESSAGE = "{0}Validation Error (ValidateReqdAndOpt)";

    private boolean applyValidator = true;
    private String validatorMessage = null;

    public ValidateReqdAndOpt() {
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object t) throws ValidatorException {
        // ApplyValidator should be set before starting (defaults to True).
        // if FALSE, the validator just returns.
        // if TRUE, the validator checks that All assigned components are either blank or that ALL required components have values
        if (!applyValidator) {
            // validator is not required
            return;
        }

        List<UIInput> reqds = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean noneHaveValues = true;
        boolean allHaveValues = true;

        // go through the required fields first, and chack if any/all have values
        for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            UIInput input = (UIInput) uic.getAttributes().get("required" + i);
            if (input == null) {
                break;  // no more required fields
            }
            reqds.add(input);
            Object submittedValue = input.getSubmittedValue();
            boolean thisIsNullOrBlank = isNullOrBlank(submittedValue);
            noneHaveValues = noneHaveValues && thisIsNullOrBlank;
            allHaveValues = allHaveValues && !thisIsNullOrBlank;
        }
        if (allHaveValues) {
            return;         // all required fields are filled in, so VALID
            // This includes ther case where there are zero required fields
        }
        
        // At least one REQD field is blank - are all (Reqd and Opt) fields blank?
        if (noneHaveValues) {
            // all REQD fields are blank.
            // Now go though the optional fields and check that they are also all blank
            for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                UIInput input = (UIInput) uic.getAttributes().get("optional" + i);
                if (input == null) {
                    break;  // no more optional fields
                }
                Object submittedValue = input.getSubmittedValue();
                boolean thisIsNullOrBlank = isNullOrBlank(submittedValue);
                noneHaveValues = noneHaveValues && thisIsNullOrBlank;
            }
            if (noneHaveValues) {
                return;     // all required and optional fields are empty, so VALID
            }
        }
        // To get here, at least one field has a value, but not all required
        // fields are present, so the validation FAILS

        if (!reqds.isEmpty()) {
            reqds.forEach((input) -> {
                input.setValid(false);  // mark all REQD field as invalid
            });
        }
        String errorMessage = getValidatorMessage(uic);
        String label = getLabel(uic);
        String msg = MessageFormat.format(errorMessage,
                ( isNullOrBlank(label) ? "" : label + ": "));
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, null));
    }
    
    private String getValidatorMessage(UIComponent uic) {
        // firstly check if the attribute was supplied.
        if ( !isNullOrBlank(this.validatorMessage) ) {
            return this.validatorMessage;
        }
        // if not, try the component's tag
        String requiredMessage = (String) uic.getAttributes().get("validatorMessage");
        if ( !isNullOrBlank(requiredMessage)) {
            return requiredMessage;
        }
        // when all also fails, return a default string
        return DEFAULT_VALIDATOR_MESSAGE;
    }
    
    private String getLabel(UIComponent uic) {
        return (String) uic.getAttributes().get("label");
    }
    
    public Boolean isApplyValidator() {
        return applyValidator;
    }

    public void setApplyValidator(Boolean applyValidator) {
        if (applyValidator != null) {
            this.applyValidator = applyValidator;
        }
    }

    public String getValidatorMessage() {
        return validatorMessage;
    }

    public void setValidatorMessage(String validatorMessage) {
        this.validatorMessage = validatorMessage;
    }
    
    private boolean isNullOrBlank(String s) {
        return ((null == s) || s.isBlank());
    }

    private boolean isNullOrBlank(Object obj) {
        return ((null == obj) || (obj instanceof String) && isNullOrBlank((String) obj));
    }
}
```

Example usage (using Primefaces 8):

```
        <h:panelGroup id="poDelPnl" >
             <h3>Place of Delivery #{createIE815Bean.PODelGroupDNA ? ' (does not apply)':' '}</h3>

             <h:inputHidden id="poDelHidden" value="0" >
                 <u:validateReqdAndOpt 
                     applyValidator="#{createIE815Bean.PODelGroupOptional}" 
                     validatorMessage="Either both of Place of Delivery Trader Name, 
                                    and City must be supplied, or no group fields" />
                 <f:attribute name="required1" value="#{poDelComponent1}" />
                 <f:attribute name="required2" value="#{poDelComponent2}" />
                 <f:attribute name="optional1" value="#{poDelComponent5}" />
            </h:inputHidden>    
            <p:message for="poDelHidden" />
                        
            <p:panelGrid  columns="3" styleClass="ui-noborder" >

                <p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Trader Identification" />
                <p:inputText id="poDelTId" value="#{createIE815Bean.PODelTraderId}" 
                             binding="#{poDelComponent5}" >
                    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@this @next" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message id="poDelTIdMsg" for="@previous" />

      etc. etc.
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in Mojarra. Try removing `managed=true` from `@FacesValidator`.

Comment: I remove managed=true and it works fine. In this case it doesn't matter but elsewhere I want to take advantage of @Inject into the validator, for which I understand managed=true is required, I've just checked with Wildfly 21.0.1 / Mojarra 2.3.14.SP01 and it has the same issue.

Comment: Also now tried with TomEE8.0.5 / MyFaces 2.3.7 and got another error, although different. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.faces.validator.Validator.validate(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, javax.faces.component.UIComponent, Object)" because the return value of "org.apache.myfaces.cdi.validator.FacesValidatorCDIWrapper.getWrapped()" is null`